# What happened to the GRASS Browser in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

In the past I could display the imported layers in the GRASS toolbox within QGIS. This was possible under the tab "Browser" as you see in the image.
[image]

Lately I'm missing this tab. The QGIS version is 2.12.1 and the GRASS version 6. But I had the same issue with older QGIS versions.

How can I bring back the browser tab or what alternative option do I have to display the available layers of the mapset?

Comment: It is the new GRASS plugin. You need to open first a Location and then you can use the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately not. In the Toolbox there is nothing and in the QGIS Browser I also can't see anything. Should it look like the above?

Answer (score 3):

The **GRASS Location Browser** has been removed in the latest versions of QGIS along with tools related to adding layers. A progress report can be seen here:

[QGIS GRASS Plugin Upgrade Progress](http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/progress.html):

[image: GRASS progress]